# unique_ptr<> v shared_ptr<> in regards to destruction policy

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been teaching myself the smart pointers that are part of C++0x and came across something that feels inconsistent to me.  Specifically, how the destruction policy of unique_ptr<> and shared_ptr<> are handled.

For unique_ptr<>, you can specialize std::default_delete<> and from then on unless you explicitly request a different destruction policy, the new default will be used.

Consider the following:

```
struct some_c_type;

some_c_type *construct_some_c_type();
void destruct_some_c_type(some_c_type *);

namespace std  {
    template <> struct default_delete<some_c_type> {
        void operator()(some_c_type *ptr) {
            destruct_some_c_type(ptr);
        }
     };
}
```

Now, once that's in place, unique_ptr<> will use the appropriate destruction policy by default:

```
// Because of the specialization, this will use destruct_some_c_type
std::unique_ptr<some_c_type> var(construct_some_c_type());
```

Now compare this to shared_ptr<>.  With shared_ptr<>, you need to explicitly request the appropriate destruction policy or it defaults to using operator delete:

```
// error, will use operator delete 
std::shared_ptr<some_c_type> var(construct_some_c_type());

// correct, must explicitly request the destruction policy
std::shared_ptr<some_c_type> var(construct_some_c_type(),
                                 std::default_delete<some_c_type>());
```

Two questions.

1. Am I correct that shared_ptr<> requires the destruction policy to be specified every time it's used or am I missing something?
2. If I'm not missing something, any idea why the two are different?

P.S. The reason I care about this is my company does a lot of mixed C and C++ programming.  The C++ code often needs to use C-style objects so the ease of specifying a different default destruction policy is quite important to me.

Comment: Is that suppose to be `std::default_delete<some_c_type>()`? And on a side note, unless it's fixed in C++0x and I'm about to find out, all three of those are vexing.

Comment: @GMan - thanks, that was a typo.  Why do you consider them all vexing (I personally find unique_ptr<> quite a clean design)?

Comment: @RSamuel: I meant the vexing parse; in C++03 those are all function declarations.

Comment: If nobody answers this, by the way, I would recommend posting it on comp.lang.c++.moderated, I'm sure someone there knows. I'll do it if you would like, I'm very curious about this.

Comment: @GMan - that would be much appreciated.

Comment: @RSam: Alrighty, I'll give people 24 hours to answer it here before I post there.

Comment: @GMan - BTW, are you sure those are vexing parses?  Since `construct_some_c_type` is a function and not a type, I believe that means we are missing an important condition for a vexing parse.

Comment: @GMan: under the circumstances, this is really more of a question of comp.std.c++. Neither of these is really part of C++ as currently defined, and at least to me, the real question is: "Is this difference between shared_ptr gratuitous or intentional?" Right now, it *looks* like it may be gratuitous, but...

Comment: @RSam: You're right, duh on my part. @Jerry: I agree. Perhaps you post it instead :3

Comment: I'm not very sure whether that would be the recommended usage of `unique_ptr`, though. You can specify your destructor explicitly: `std::unique_ptr<X, XDeleter> p;`. The difference might also be due to the fact that `unique_ptr` is supposed to be very low-overhead, so there's probably nothing better to do than to make the deleter part of the type, whereas this is not quite so with shared_ptr.

Comment: @UncleBens - why do you think specializing `default_delete<>` is not recommended usage?  `default_delete<>` has no behavior that depends on the type so in and of itself, there is no reason to make it a template.  Based on this, the only reason I can see to make it a template is to be able to specialize it.

Comment: `default_delete` seems to be specialized for arrays as `default_delete<T[]>`, so you can have `unique_ptr<X>(new X)` and `unique_ptr<X[]>(new X[n])`. May-be there are types that can only be disposed of with one particular function and in no other way. But still it seems to me that explicit is better than implicit here (e.g if you see that the pointer doesn't come from `new`, not specifying a deleter is likely an error).

Answer (score 4):

I think the question boils down to why std::shared_ptr can have no associated deleter (in which case it just calls `delete`) rather than constructing a `std::default_delete` by default. (No idea. If the intention was that `default_delete` is for specializing, one would expect it to be used by `shared_ptr`.)

Otherwise there are trade-offs.

It is better to have fewer template arguments. Boost's reference mentions that this allows a factory to change the allocation scheme without the change affecting the user of the factory.

A `unique_ptr` on the other hand is supposed to be very light-weight. How would you store the deleter with zero space overhead (in case of a functor without members) if it wasn't part of the type (GCC uses tuple, where memberless objects don't take memory space)?

---

Subjectively, I think I'd prefer:

```
unique_ptr<FILE, FCloser> f(fopen(x, y));
```

to

```
unique_ptr<FILE> f(fopen(x, y)); //default_delete<FILE> has been specialized
```

In the first case there's nothing to guess. If the resource does not come from `new` or `new[]`, a deleter has to be explicitly given.

Comment: I agree: Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: @UncleBens - one issue with the implicit/explicit discussion is the standard specifically allows allows for implicit which will always compile but could cause undefined behavior.  If you always had to specify the deleter even for a simple `delete` or `delete []` that may be okay.  But as it is, it's easy to forget, the build will succeed and such a bug could be easy to miss.

Comment: Specialize it for FILE and the like to static_assert? :) But even if you specialize it, you'll need to remember to include the header with the specializations?

Comment: for types like FILE, you do need to include the header file.  But for local C types, we can include the specialization in the same file that declares the C type's constructor/destructor.

Comment: The problem with this syntax is that it uglifies things like interfacing with a C api. I'd like to be able to do something like unique_ptr<THandle> ptr(LIB_T_Make_a_T(params....), LIB_T_Destroy_a_T); where the type of LIB_T_Destroy_a_T is void(THandle*)

Comment: Oh and I don't want to pollute std:: with my own template specializations.